# Why Antiforgery CookieSecurePolicy not applying?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

I want to make my Antiforgery cookies secured, so I add some changes to my code:

```
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddAntiforgery(opts => {
        opts.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        opts.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        opts.Cookie.Domain = "localhost";
        opts.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    });
```

But even after I set secure policy, there are no changes on my cookies:
[Antiforgery cookies not secured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/445Md.png), browser connection is secured (https).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way for .net core 2.1 is to add the next code to your Startup.cs:

```
        var cookiePolicyOptions = new CookiePolicyOptions
        {
            MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict,
            Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
        };
        app.UseCookiePolicy(cookiePolicyOptions);
```

You also could check documentation about cookies setup [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-5.0).